# Redirected folders and roaming profiles issues

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, roaming-profile, folder-redirection

At the beginning:

I've been working as an extra in a new company (it's a school) for two weeks, so I don't really know the rules/configuration.
After weeks of working there, users started having problems (it started with one user at first).

Problems:

1. (This problem has existed before) Very long login and logout time.
2. After successful login, the user has a black screen with a white cursor and only the "My computer" context is displayed (as I remember well). Explorer exe helps after restarting from the task manager, but not for long, because when the user starts working on a folder or right-clicks on the desktop or directory, the explorer.exe process hangs, turns off and we return to the starting point.
3. I don't know why, but users have problems with conflicts in the synchronization center and files do not synchronize on some users.
4. Problem with exceeded profile space. "You have exceeded your Profile Storage Space"

Errors:
In the event viewer there is Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, there is also a fatal error on some endings:
0x3d55 package family microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe

We use redirected folders and redierected profiles (together with AppData).
I really don't like the combination of these two "technologies" and methods. I would like to get away from these technologies, but users must have their files on different computers within the school

My questions:

1. How to deal with black screen issues?
2. If I suddenly stop redirecting AppData in GPO, will it cause anything? If so, what?
3. Is the long user loading time caused by roaming profiles and their size?
4. What are the alternatives to Roaming profiles & redirected profiles? What could I potentially migrate to? (Users do not work remotely) (we have MS365 a1 licenses)

AD: Windows server 2016
PC: Windows 10/11 and Windows 7 (Interestingly, there are no problems with explorer.exe on Windows 7)

Comment: The answer to 4. should be obvious, if it is really just about the files: configure a Home drive inside the user profile, which is a mounted network share. And users should place all files they still need inside their home drive.

Comment: @Martin actually, I would have to ask them to move all files previously saved on the desktop to a shared drive and inform them that the files from the desktop will not be "saved" if they do not save them on a shared drive. And the accounts will remain local

Comment: Home folder is the same like folder redirected?

Comment: Sounds like a disk of a file server is full where the profiles are stored. Or an quota issue on the file server where the roaming profiles are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from roaming profiles to a home drive may solve multiple issues here. A home folder/drive is a network drive mapped from a file server and is usually configured via the user's active directory settings but occasionally user login scripts are executed to map the home drive. Event viewer would be a good place to check if anything else is taking a long time prior to profile/session loading.

You may also have a disk space issue if everyone roams from computer to computer. Time to clean up old profiles and assign a computer or desk to each person. Hopefully you don't have a synchronization issue due to files being locked/in use by the same person on multiple computers.

It should be simple enough to remove/disable the AppData redirection (assuming that's the temp data in a user's profile) once everyone has an assigned computer they've logged into. You'll want to copy it from wherever it was redirected to the normal folder. I'd suggest testing this first with all applications.